# Why is pidstat not reflecting the change I made in CPU affinity using taskset?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, ps

I wanted to change the CPU affinity of a process with PID 1132, so I used the following command and successfully changed its CPU affinity:

```
abc@abc:~$ taskset -pc 1132 
pid 1132's current affinity list: 0
```

But when I try to see the CPU of that PID 1132 is using, I get the same old CPU ie. CPU 3

```
abc@abc:~$ pidstat |grep '1132'
10:01:37 AM      1132    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00     3  runsv
```

Why is it so?

Comment: Unless there is no reason to use a different CPU, the OS would use the same CPU for a process. I would increase the load of the system. This will leader to a higher chance that the process will run on a different CPU.

Comment: Yes, after some time the OS switched to CPU 0.

Comment: I saw the same behavior during my tests. What solved it for me was to simply restart the process, this time via `taskset -c <core_num> <my command>`.

Answer (score 0):

The affinity list is wrong. You should assign the process 1132 to one or more cpus. Currently the affinity list is 0 which is wrong. If you want to assign to the CPU 0, you should use 0x00000001, as:

```
0x00000001 is processor #0

0x00000003 is processors #0 and #1

0xFFFFFFFF is all processors (#0 through #31).
```

The  CPU  affinity  is  represented as a bitmask, with the lowest order bit corresponding to the first logical CPU and the highest order bit corresponding to the last logical CPU.  Not all CPUs may exist on a given system but a mask may specify more CPUs than are present. \

A  retrieved  mask will  reflect  only the bits that correspond to CPUs physically on the system.  If an invalid mask is given (i.e., one that corresponds to no valid CPUs on the current system) an error is returned.

On my linux (kernel 4.0), I am not able to assign CPU list 0x0 to a process:

```
# taskset  -p 0x0 1089
pid 1089's current affinity mask: ff000000ff0000ff00ff
taskset: failed to set pid 1089's affinity: Invalid argument
```

Comment: This isn't true; you may set CPU affinity also by using the `-c` param, in which you specify a numerical list instead of a bitmask. Check `man taskset`.